Stucco: Repair or replace when cracks are apparent?
I have a painter doing exterior paint for my home. He told me there were cracks on the stucco and that with new paint this might be more visible. I have included a picture. Is this something that can be repaired, or do I need to replace everything?
He's telling me I need to replace wall-to-wall. The question is do I need to replace the entire area, the bottom section, etc. Thank you!
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dle9abiznpivc1gih5xzh/IMG_7499.JPG?rikey=91cfeaab8mesq1maxdzgn11zk&dl=0

Haven’t looked at your picture (you can add it to your question), but if the stucco is solid, people usually fill cracks with caulk, use elastomeric paint, and move on.

Aloysius is correct, most cracks are superficial, although not desired. They can be carefully caulked, since a sloppy job can be as bad as the crack is. By the way, the link to the picture does not work.  Not all of the characters of the link are included in the active link itself. When I copy and paste the whole link, it still does not work.
